# CSS for one-page Website with 100%-element on top

Tags: html, css

I need to create a div-element, which has 100% width and height for the visible part of the screen. Below this there should be another div-element with variable height, which can only be seen, if the user scrolls down. It is like a one-page website...

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/sopk6vx3/

```css
#main {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#overlay {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#overlay section {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 94%;
  height: 90%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 2% 3%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <header>Navigation</header>
  <footer>Footer of main-element</footer>
</div>
<div id="tour">
  Here is some tour-information about the product
</div>

<div id="overlay">
  <section>Main Content</section>
</div>
```

Via click on a navigation element the #overlay will be fade in to show the content.

So how do I do the correct CSS for the #main and #tour element? As in the fiddle it doesn't work.

And could the overlay-css been optimized?

Comment: In order to scroll down to your page, the #main should be filled. 100% of nothing = nothing. You just cant do that with no content. The other way is to specify a height. But i dont think thats what you want.

Comment: Is there are reason that you are building this: luke.sno.wden.co.uk/full-screen-vertical-scroll#fsvs-initial-setup

Comment: You might really like this : https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js. And combined with Bootstrap 3.3, I've achieved an half an hour site like this : http://brightrymer.com/.

Comment: Thanks. These are great links. I like that examples. But as I'm using angular.js, I didn't need JQuery so far. And I don't want to use JQuery just for that scrolling (which I really like)